# Arm Assembly: LDRH instruction to C

Tags: assembly, decompilation, c, arm

I've been reversing an asm checksum code for the last days, and I've managed to understand how it completly works, except for one instruction; **ldrh**

The info I've been able to found says that it's basically a ldr instruction which loads a half word (2 bytes). But the problem is that the ldr() instruction has a lot of variants and there's no info about how this one would be wrote in pseudo C.

Specifically my instruction is:
**ldrh  r3,[r12,r3]**
If it were a normal ldr, the pseudo code will be
**r3 = r12[r3];**
(r12 is an addres to a memory place so I don't understand what it really does..Does it loads the value at r12+r3 into r3?

Comment: r3 = ((unsigned short*)r12)[r3], sorry, previous comment was not correct, i deleted it.

Comment: @ws So it is actually getting a 2 bytes value which is at address r12[r3] (r12+r3) right?

Comment: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/CIHDGFEG.html  - the definition of ldr is still here, I just didn't take in account endianess correctly

Comment: Yes, you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As specified by @w s , the C representation of the assembly instruction **ldrh r3,[r12,r3]** would be:

```
r3 = ((unsigned short*)r12)[r3]
```

For more documentation, visit:

http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/CIHDGFEG.html